# Why am I getting "Configuration property is not defined"?

Tags: node.js, npm, config

When I run my `index.js` file, I am getting `Configuration property "mail.host" is not defined`. I don't understand why.

`config.get('name')` works fine. I set my `NODE_ENV=production`. Can anyone please help?

**`index.js`**

```
const config = require('config');
console.log(config.get('name'));
console.log(config.get('mail.host'));
```

**`production.json`**

```
{
  "name": "My app - production",
  "mail": {
    "host": "production-server"
  }
}
```

Comment: `production.json` should be in a folder named `config`

Answer (score 0):

It works after restarting my Terminal.